# AVR-GCC: Registers UDR0, UBRR0H, and UBRR0L undeclared

Tags: microcontroller

I am working with an AVR Atmel 32-bit AT32 UC3A3 microcontroller and I am trying to write C code for receiving UART. The code is giving me this error:

[image: registers undeclared]

I think the compiler can't find the iomap file for this MCU; when I add a temporary iom328.h for the other MCU, it works.

I need to find the one for the MCU I am working with. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this, or has anyone experienced the same issue?

```c
ISR(USART_UDRE_vect) {
    static char* uart_tx_p = uart_tx_buffer; /*!< Pointer to TX buffer */
    uint8_t info; 

    info = *uart_tx_p++;  

    if (info == 0) {
        uart_tx_p = uart_tx_buffer;
        uart_flag.tx = 1;
    } else {
        UDR0 = info;
    }
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
    static uint8_t uart_rx_cnt; 
    uint8_t info; 

    info = UDR0;  

    if (!uart_flag.rx) {
        uart_rx_buffer[uart_rx_cnt] = info;
        uart_rx_cnt++;
    } else {
        uart_rx_buffer[uart_rx_cnt] = 0;  
        uart_flag.rx = 1;
        uart_rx_cnt = 0;
    }
}

#define F_CPU
void uart0_init(uint16_t baudrate) {
    uart_flag.tx = 1;
    uart_flag.rx = 0;

    uint8_t speed = 16;

    baudrate = (F_CPU/(speed*baudrate)) - 1;

    UBRR0H = (baudrate & 0x0F00) >> 8;
    UBRR0L = (baudrate & 0x00FF);

    UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);  
}
```

Comment: You're missing a / in one of your single-line comments. Or a semicolon somewhere. Maybe something in the line you blocked out would be a hint. But you'd have to actually post your code (formatted readably, as text and not as an an image) and not just your screenshotted error messages for us to help.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the platform header. I don't know AVR32 but AVR8 uses `#include <avr/io.h>`.  Read the toolchain docs for what header(s) are required. Also read through your macros, you have `#define F_CPU /* empty */` so `F_CPU` is transformed to null, so `baudrate = (/(speed*baudrate)) - 1;` which is expecting an expression.

Comment: The 32-bit [UC3A3](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc32058.pdf) is completely different from the 8-bit AVRs. The USART is completely different, so the code you have (presumably from an 8-bit AVR) will not work at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just have avr32/io.h header file on top, and when I browse the file, it has the line for microcontroller at32 uc3a3, and I have a header file for this MCU as well in the avr32 library/folder. I do not know why still the program when compiled, does not recognize registers. Do I need an IOMAP header file to add manually for my MCU?

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes the code is for a MCU 8 bit, I am a beginner in microcontroller programming, sorry for asking simple questions. Can I ask what I would  need to change in the code to work for a 32 bit? is there any sample for AVR UC3A3 32 bit that I can look into that?

Comment: @spn2023 - Hi, (a) You posted an "answer" but it still asked for help. As you are the OP, you would only write an answer if you fully solved the problem yourself & the topic can be closed *with no more help needed*. If you ask for more advice in an "answer" then it becomes a *question* again! For the Stack Exchange "model" to work, people must not ask for help in an answer - it is supposed to be a clear *solution*. (b) Now that you have an answer to your original question, you must not change the question (or add a different one) as that will make the existing answer look wrong/incomplete.

Comment: (continued) (c) It seems that the answer here pointed you in the right direction. I suggest you consider accepting that answer to close *this* question and ask a new question if you have a new problem. || This Q&A approach is the main difference with Stack Exchange. Please see the [tour] & [help] for more details. Thanks..

Comment: Sure, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It appears the code you have posted is from an 8-bit Atmel ATMega microcontroller. For these devices identifiers such as `UBRR0H` are defined by avr-gcc by including `<avr/io.h>`. They represent physical register addresses in the microcontroller, and being low level access the code is not portable to devices with different register names an arrangements.

The device you are apparently trying to compile for, the [AT32UC3A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc32058.pdf), is a completely different breed of microcontroller (for one it's 32-bit not 8-bit). It's peripherals and register maps are completely different. Looking at the [datasheet page 339](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc32058.pdf) we can see the registers are in no way similar:

[image: Partial register map]

You will need to (re)write code specific to the MCU you are targetting.

At a cursory glance, you could look into using [ASF](https://asf.microchip.com/docs/latest/uc3a3_a4/html/group__serial__group.html) from Microchip which includes demos and examples for various microcontrollers and peripherals. Beyond that, you'll have to do some searching for examples or try to read/understand the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, I was spending too much time and right, I was confused why register names are different. I will look into examples in ASF. Thanks again.

Comment: Can I ask where I can find avr32-gcc library? I am trying to compile a sample usart-interrupt code for avr32 and it is giving me error for header files as I copied header files from avr-gcc library earlier

Comment: @spn2023 I would install Microchip Studio (formerly Atmel Studio), which includes the ASF files and avr-gcc files for both the 8-bit and 32-bit MCUs.